# Java Constructor being called multiple times

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, constructor

I'm creating a PokerHand class and using JUnit tests to test it, and for some reason my constructor is called 8 times when I call it in one test method, when I create one PokerHand object.

PokerHand constructor (added a print statement to see how many times it was being called, prints 8 separate times):

```
//Constructor
public PokerHand (Card cardOne, Card cardTwo, Card cardThree, Card cardFour, Card cardFive) {
    System.out.println("creating hand...");
    //Initialize value array
    value = new int[6];
    //Initialize cards list, add cards, and check for duplicates
    cards = new ArrayList<Card>();

    cards.add(cardOne);
    if (cards.contains(cardTwo)) {
        throw new DuplicateCardException();
    } else cards.add(cardTwo);
    if (cards.contains(cardThree)) {
        throw new DuplicateCardException();
    } else cards.add(cardThree);
    if (cards.contains(cardFour)) {
        throw new DuplicateCardException();
    } else cards.add(cardFour);
    if (cards.contains(cardFive)) {
        throw new DuplicateCardException();
    } else cards.add(cardFive);

    determineValueOfHand();
}
```

Test case:

```
    @Test
  public void testFlush() {
      PokerHand a = new PokerHand(D10, DJ, DQ, DK, DA);
  }
```

I've been staring at a screen for some time and I'm new to JUnit tests and eclipse, so I'm sure I'm just missing a small detail. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What else do you have in your test class?  Must be something else since `D10`, for example, is not declared here.

Comment: Can you provide the full code for the class containing your tests?

Comment: @Brick I created all 52 distinct Card objects in my test class

Comment: Please turn to the help center; and read about creating a **minimal** **viable** example. You dont want to post **all** your code. But code that compiles and that shows the problem. (and for the record: alone the activity of creating such an example will very often eliminate the need to ask here; because that very often will make you find your bug yourself - because you try to isolate it).

Comment: @Trey the class consists of 52 distinct Card objects

Comment: @Lanre Please post the ENTIRE test class.

Comment: Another hint: change your println to ("PokerHand ctor " + this) - you want to be sure that determineValueOfHand() for example doesn't create **other** PokerHand objects! Thus it would help to see which PokerHand objects get created; and you could do a println for a in your testcase too!

Comment: You could also print the stack trace to see what's calling the constructor.

Comment: @GhostCat that was it! Code got messy and that print led me to determineValueOfHand(), thanks!

Comment: @Lanre If you don't mind; then I will turn my comment into an answer; so you can accept it ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat by all means!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hint that according to your comment fixed the problem: probably your method *determineValueOfHand()* erroneously creates **other** PokerHand objects.

In order to check for that; I recommend that

1. your constructor
2. your testcase

does println()s using the object reference. In addition to that, you could put entry/exit traces into your ctor! That makes it more obvious in which order constructor calls happen.

Comment: Or put breakpoint in constructor and check call stack in the *debugger* when it breaks.